# Why doesn't Puppeteer work with multiple uploads?

Tags: javascript, node.js, chromium, puppeteer, headless

In my HTML, I have an input element as follows:

```
<input id="input-44" name="input44[]" type="file" multiple>
```

In my JavaScript code (skipping some boilerplate), the following works:

```
const elementHandle = await page.$("#input-44");
elementHandle.uploadFile("/path/to/file");
await page.click("#upload-button");
```

According to the docs:

https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md

uploadFiles should be able to accept multiple files

When I change my code to:

```
const elementHandle = await page.$("#input-44");
const files = ["/path/to/file", "/path/to/file2"];
elementHandle.uploadFile(...files);
await page.click("#upload-button");
```

the upload doesn't work anymore. Why is this?

Comment: I've tested your file upload code on my Redmine task and it does upload files (pptr v1.5). Have you tried logging errors, running the code in headful mode? - there could be other errors

Comment: Perhaps it's a typo in your code, above, but given that `uploadFile` returns a `Promise` like all other puppeteer methods, why aren't you using `await` for that line of code?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is the problem, but there's no `await` before `elementHandle.uploadFile(...files);`

```
const elementHandle = await page.$("#input-44");
const files = ["/path/to/file", "/path/to/file2"];
await elementHandle.uploadFile(...files);
await page.click("#upload-button");
```

Not sure why the code worked to begin with if it didn't have `await`, though.

Answer (score -1):

for alternative i think you can loop each element in paths to upload

```
const elementHandle = await page.$("#input-44");
const files = ["/path/to/file", "/path/to/file2"];
for (let index = 0; index < files.length; index++) {
   const filePath = files[index];
   await elementHandle.uploadFile(filePath);
}
await page.click("#upload-button");
```

Comment: for some sites, it triggers the upload function more than once.